# PC black screens and is unresponsive unless I turn psu off and wait

Tags: display, hardware-failure

My problem is my PC screen goes black and seemingly turns off but it is still powered on and running. It wont respond to the reset buttom and qont turn back on unless I turn off the psu switch for 15 minutes. Happens randomly without any high temperatures being shown.

It stopped doing it for the past 2 weeks but has now started again. Unplugging all hardware possible wont make it start up again I always have to wait. If I dont wait long enough it will usually black screen very soon after starting properly.

WINDOWS 8 64BIT. Seasonic 80+gold 350watt psu. CORE2DUO 2.8. 4GM DDR800 CORSAIR RAM TESRED FINE. GTS450 GPU. ASUS P5KPLCM MOBO.

Comment: Problem must be the power supply. I found a donor to test in my system and havent had the issue again. Taking it in for replacement next week. If they tell me what caused the fault ill post again if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The GTS450 minimum PSU requirement according to the official nVidia site is 400W.

I tend to agree, since only the card can draw with ease 125W in certain tested scenarios (without overclocking). That, plus the CPU would push things to the limit. It would in most cases work with a new PSU, but probably yours is pretty old by now.

Just take another 400W+ PSU and test your system with it. It should work. If it does, just get a new PSU and you're out of the problem in the easy way.

Comment: I didnt see that minimum spec when I bought it. Psu was bought new last year. Peak load on the psu was 160watt total completely maxing gpu and cpu including all drives and cards when I tested a while back. Idle 65. I havent been able to find another psu to test yet.

Comment: It may have some dried capacitors.

Comment: I think it must be something getting hot.  Its now getting warmer above 30c and pc wont stay on more than 10 minutes. But no temps are high in an app called speedfan.